# Progress Dialog dont move

Tags: android

Hi I try show progress dialog when mymethod is running with code that below. When thread starts the progress dialog stop I dismiss it at the end of the method that called in thread. How can I solve this?

```
>mDialog = new ProgressDialog(DealActivity.this);


    mDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.show();
        mDialog.setProgress(0);



        new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                mymethod();
            }

        }.start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AsyncTask` instead of thread. Show your `ProgressDialog` in `onPreExecute()` method call your `mymethod()` in `doInBackGround()` and dismiss you progressDialog in `onPostExecute()`.

Follow this tutorial for better explanation.

[Android Threads, Handlers and AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

You'll also find this tutorial related to your need.

[Managing AsyncTask, progress dialog and screen orientation](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2011/11/for-my-app-moustachify-everything-i-was.html)